# Python Loop - Isolating whole integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print the entire integer in this loop. I tried setting the `num` column as a list, but got the same output. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np

for line in open("data.txt"):
    column = line.split()
    name = column[0]
    num = column[4]
    int(num)
    for x in num:
        print(x)
```

Actual Output:

```
1
0
1
3
3
6
5
0
```

Expected output:

```
10 
13 
36 
50
```

**UPDATE** - amending the code the following way allowed for the integers to be iterated. It's mentioned in the comments below that I append to a list - this turned out to be the right idea.

```
num = [int(column[4])]
    for x in num:
        print(x)
```

This gives me an output of:

```
10
13
36
50
```

Comment: can you add you're `data.text` file content ?

Comment: you are handlign strings from readin the file. If you iterade a string you get single characters ...  simply `print(num)` - and remove the `for x in num:`

Comment: @PatrickArtner, yes, that takes care of printing - but what if I want to do something more than print those integers, like foreach of those integers compute a value. I guess the question here is how to make `for x in num` work.

Comment: you convert them into numbers .... and stuff them in a list or something like that: `my_num_list.append(int(num))` and after reading them all you use them.

Comment: That should actually give you a TypeError on the `for x in num:` line, since integers aren't iterable.

Comment: Indeed, how is it you don't get an error? Did you override the `int` object?

Comment: @glibdud - yes, you're right the version posted above does - I've edited it

Comment: If you're saying your "update" is the solution to the problem, you should post it as an answer and accept it rather than appending it to the question. Although note that you're still adding a `for` loop where you don't need one. You can replace those three lines with just `num = int(column[4])` and `print(num)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `int(num)` line isn't actually doing anything for you, since you're not assigning the result to anything. And it's unclear what the purpose of the `for x in num:` loop is, but as mentioned in the comments it's causing each character of the string `num` to be printed individually. This will do what you're asking:

```
for line in open("data.txt"):
    column = line.split()
    name = column[0]
    num = column[4]
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could, please post a sample for "data.txt" to fully understand your output.

It seems that for every line, column 4 holds a single digit, and you want to print a final number that is actually the digits combined every two rows.

One way you could do that is to store the digits in a list and then print after reading the file:

```
num = list()
for line in open("data.txt"):
    column = line.split()
    num.append(column[4])

# You would get num = ['1', '0', '1', '3', '3', '6', '5', '0']

for index, x in enumerate(num[::2]):
    print("".join([x, num[index*2+1]]))
```

Although this would produce an error if you don't have an even number of lines in "data.txt". You could then avoid the last line by using `enumerate(num[:len(num)-len(num)%2:2])`